# Get nth child node without knowing node name Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have xml like this:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>
      <node4>
        <node5>
          <node6>
          </node6>
          <node7>
          </node7>
        </node5>
      </node4>
    </node3>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

How can I get the name of the 6th node - assuming I don't know the node's name is "node6"?

I currently have:

```
def text = <xml from above>
def list = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def text = <xml from above>
def node = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)[0]
5.times { node  = node.children()[0] }
assert node.name() == "node6"
```

Comment: I prefer `def fifthchild = (1..5).inject(node) { n, _ -> n.children()[0] }` ;-)